# Wedge product of a 2-form

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

Given the 1-form, $$\alpha = dz - pdx - qdy,$$ I can calculate $$d\alpha = -dp\wedge dx - dq \wedge dy = dx \wedge dp + dy \wedge dq, $$ but I'm not so sure how to calculate $d\alpha \wedge d\alpha$.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Distribute: $d\alpha \wedge d\alpha = dx \wedge dp \wedge dx \wedge xp + dx \wedge dp \wedge dy \wedge dq + dy \wedge dq \wedge dx \wedge dp + dy \wedge dq \wedge dy \wedge dq$. Two of these terms are zero. The other two can be combined.

Comment: Oh wow. That's very simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{split} 
d\alpha\wedge d\alpha &=(dx\wedge dp+dy\wedge dq)\wedge (dx\wedge dp+dy\wedge dq)\\
&=dx\wedge dp\wedge dy\wedge dq+dy\wedge dq\wedge dx\wedge dp\\
&=2dx\wedge dp\wedge dy\wedge dq
\end{split}$$

Use the fact that $\alpha\wedge \beta=(-1)^{\text{degree}(\alpha)\text{degree}(\beta)}\beta\wedge \alpha$ if $\beta$ and alpha are homogeneous.